# CUDA: ptxas fatal : Unresolved extern function '_ZN15Rel_CoordinatesIdE9calculateERK11CoordinatesIdES4_'

Tags: cuda, ptxas

I am trying to calculate relative distance between points with user defined classes in CUDA. I have a Coordinates class and a Relative Coordinate class to store coordinates and calculate Relative Coodinates.

```cpp
// class.cuh

#pragma once

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#define CUDA_HOST __host__ 
#define CUDA_DEVICE __device__
#else
#define CUDA_HOST 
#define CUDA_DEVICE 
#endif 

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

template <class Typ>
class Coordinates {
    public:
    Typ x{}, y{}, z{};

    Coordinates () = default;
    Coordinates (const Typ&, const Typ&, const Typ&);
};

template <class Typ>
class Rel_Coordinates : public Coordinates<Typ> {
    public:
    // unsigned idx_a{}, idx_b{};
    Typ dist2{}, dist{}, dist_inv{};

    Rel_Coordinates () = default;

    CUDA_HOST CUDA_DEVICE 
    void calculate (const Coordinates<Typ>&, const Coordinates<Typ>&);
};
```

```cpp
template <class Typ>
Coordinates<Typ>::Coordinates(const Typ& X, const Typ& Y, const Typ& Z)
: x{X}, y{Y}, z{Z}
{}

template <class Typ>
__host__ __device__
void Rel_Coordinates<Typ>::calculate (
    const Coordinates<Typ>& element_A, 
    const Coordinates<Typ>& element_B
){
    this -> x = element_B.x - element_A.x;
    this -> y = element_B.y - element_A.y;
    this -> z = element_B.z - element_A.z;

    this -> dist2 = 0.;
    this -> dist2 += std::pow(this -> x, 2);
    this -> dist2 += std::pow(this -> y, 2);
    this -> dist2 += std::pow(this -> z, 2);

    this -> dist = std::sqrt(this -> dist2);

    this -> dist_inv = 1 / this -> dist;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cu
#include "class.cuh"

__device__ Coordinates<double> a {}, b {};
__device__ Rel_Coordinates<double> ba {};

__global__ void cal (
    Coordinates<double> & a,
    Coordinates<double> & b,
    Rel_Coordinates<double> & ba
){
    a.x = 0.;
    a.y = 0.;
    a.z = 0.;
    b.x = 0.;
    b.y = 3.;
    b.z = 4.;

    ba.calculate (a, b);
}

int main () {

    cal <<<1,1>>> (a, b, ba);

}
```

and i am compiling it using:

```
nvcc main.cu class.cu -o main
```

I am runing this on Win11 with RTX 3070 mobile GPU.

I was expecing it to calculate relative position and distance. But i got this error:

```
main.cu
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN15Rel_CoordinatesIdE9calculateERK11CoordinatesIdES4_'
```

Comment: See [`-dc`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#device-c-dc) flag for `nvcc`. For a deeper dive see [Nvidia Developer Blog: Separate Compilation and Linking of CUDA C++ Device Code](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I did try that and got the same error.

```
 nvcc -dc class.cu -o class
 nvcc -dc main.cu -o main
nvcc -arch=sm_70 class.obj main.obj -o main
```

and the error 

```
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN15Rel_CoordinatesIdE9calculateERK11CoordinatesIdES4_' in 'main.obj'
```

Comment: `-dc` is not sufficient to create an executable object.  For all at once compilation, use `-rdc=true`.